# Failed to read row 1, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 3 rows, 1 columns

Tags: android, cursor

```
Cursor c=getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { ContactsContract.Data.LOOKUP_KEY}, null,null, null);
    contacts=new ArrayList<String>();
    phno=new ArrayList<String>();
    c.moveToFirst();
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        String contactname = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String phnumber= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        contacts.add(contactname);//adding in array list
        phno.add(phnumber);//adding in array list
    }
    c.close();
```

Please help me with this error, I understand that if the column number is -1 there are no columns. How can I rectify this problem?

Here is the code and the rest are initialization.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_receive);
    actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
    int permissioncheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Receive.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
    if (permissioncheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        showContacts();
    }
    else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Receive.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,contacts);
    actv.setAdapter(adapter);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            x=actv.getListSelection();
            phone=phno.get(x).toString();
            tv.setText(phone);
        }
    });
}
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String[] permissions,int[] grantResults){
    if(requestCode==PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS){
        if(grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            showContacts();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"permission granted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you for spending your time to educate people. This website is very helpful for rookies like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your projection, second argument of `query()`:

```
new String[] { ContactsContract.Data.LOOKUP_KEY}
```

You are asking the query to only return the `LOOKUP_KEY` column. So when you try to find the column indices for `DISPLAY_NAME` and `NUMBER` later, `getColumnIndex()` returns -1 as it cannot find those columns. Fix this by changing your projection to this:

```
new String[] { 
        ContactsContract.Data.LOOKUP_KEY,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
}
```

You could also get rid of `ContactsContract.Data.LOOKUP_KEY` if you're not using it anywhere.

Comment: i am getting two names of same contact in the array list. Is there any problem with the remaining code? I am not able to figure it out. Please explain.

Comment: @saikumarkolisetty Nothing I can see in that code. If you have a separate issue, please feel free to ask a new question.